# Single Expression in the SELECT clause is supported with UDTF's

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

This is the below query I am using and every time I get the below semantic analysis error.

```
hive> select explode(test2.purchased_item.product_id) AS prodID, 
explode(test2.purchased_item.timestamps) AS time from testingtable2 test2;

FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Only a single expression in the SELECT clause
is supported with UDTF's
```

Is there any restriction with the hive I cannot use two explode in a single select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it looks like your an only use invocation of explode per SELECT as per https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode

Answer (score 0):

Use LATERAL VIEW. I took this from the "Programming Hive"

> Hive offers a LATERAL VIEW feature to allow this kind of query:

```
hive> SELECT name, sub
> FROM employees
> LATERAL VIEW explode(subordinates) subView AS sub;
```